# HTTP Status 500 Java Spring Bean

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

Доброго времени суток! Помогите знающие люди разобраться с ошибкой в простеньком вэб приложении. 
Ошибка HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'carRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.host.baseofcars.repository.CarRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**CarRepository**

```
@Repository("carRepository")
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
@Query("select s from Car s where s.userName = :userName")
Car findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
```

**CarService**

```
@Service
public interface CarService {
Car save(Car car);
boolean findByLogin(String userName, String password);
boolean findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

**CarServiceImpl**

```
@Service("carService")
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Car save(Car car) {
        return carRepository.save(car);
    }

    public boolean findByLogin(String userName, String password) {
        Car car = carRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        if(car != null && car.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean findByUserName(String userName) {
        Car car = carRepository.findByUserName(userName);

        if(car != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Нашел много подобных ошибок и методов решения (например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626804/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-autowired-spring)), но у меня не работает. Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте после @Autowired добавить @Qualifier("carRepository"). И интерфейс CarService не обязательно аннотировать как Service

Comment: покажите конфигурацию

Comment: @Qualifier не помогает.

Comment: а если просто убрать аннотацию `@Repository` из `CarRepository`?

Comment: Убрать аннотацию @Repository из CarRepository не помогло. Ошибка та же. У меня складывается впечатление что я упускаю из вида что-то более важное. Такая ожибка может свидетельствовать оо ошибках в стуркуре проекта или неправильных зависимостях?

Comment: попробуйте так:
 @Autowired
    public CarServiceImpl (CarRepository carRepository) {
        this.carRepository= carRepository;
    }

Comment: @Bukinozoid в таком случае, может нет аннотации `@EnableJpaRepositories` в конфиге? пункт 4.2.3 в документации https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Comment: EnableJpaRepositories у меня прописан в XML: <jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories"/>.    @Autowired public CarServiceImpl (CarRepository carRepository) { this.carRepository= carRepository; } - это не помогает.

Comment: Почему Spring ищет `CarRepository` в `ru.host.baseofcars.repository`, а на скриншоте имя пакета `ru.mishost.baseofcars`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вставлял текст ошибки в два захода, вот mi и потерялось. Это на описанную ошибку не влияет.

Comment: А xml конфигурацию-то можно посмотреть?

Comment: У Вас в самом начале ошибка создания бина **carController**. Что это за бин? Как Вы его создаёте? Если через **new**, то может быть похожая ошибка.